# C# Adding 4923 Lines from a text file to DataGridView by skipping blank lines

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am new to C#. I have a huge text file consisting of 4923 lines of data that I wish to add to a DataGridView. The text file has a lot of spaces and blank lines in between sentences. I want that all the blank lines and spaces be skipped and load the contents to the DataGridView. Can someone give me a solution to achieve this? Can this be achieved without using DataTables and Datasource?

If my question is not clear please let me know. There may be mistakes in my code. Please help me rectify it

Thanks

This is my code

```
public void textload()
{
        List<string> str = new List<string>();
        String st = "";

        //Path to write contents to text file
        string filename = @"E:\Vivek\contentcopy\clientlist.txt";
        Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.FileName = "";
        ofd.Filter = "csv files|*.csv|txt files|*.txt|All Files|*.*";
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        st = ofd.FileName;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ofd.FileName))
            return;

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(st);

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(lines[i]);
            string[] s = lines[i].Split(' ');
            MessageBox.Show(s.Length.ToString());
            str.Add(lines[i]);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

            if (s[i] == null && s[i] == " ") 
            {
                    continue; 
            }        

            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[i].Value=s[i];
            //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value = s[10];
            //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value = s[11];
            //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value = s[12];
            //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value = s[13];
            //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value = s[14];
            //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[15].Value = s[15];
       }

       File.WriteAllLines(filename, str);
       dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Comment: Try `.Replace(' ','').ToString()`

Comment: @LeoSarmiento Where to add the above line sir?

Comment: Can you please show us your sample text you want to parse ? `IndexOutOfBoundException` is different from `OutOfMemoryException` The number of columns in grid and in your text files are mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to filter out empty strings as soon as you've read it. This can be done with LINQ [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) and passing condition that checks string for not being whitespace only.  [String.IsNullOrWhitepspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) covers that (in addition it would check for `null` that will not happen in case of using `ReadAllLines`).

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(st)
     .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(s))
     .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks @ALexie ,now that I have filtered all empty strings ,how to load the contents to the DataGridView?

Comment: @user2614235, Just a side note:. If the file is very large in size you might get `OutOfMemoryException` if you loads complete contents at once.

Comment: @NeverHopeless you're right.I am getting IndexOutOfBound Exception at dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[i].Value=lines[i];.Can you Please tell me how to load data to DataGridview